# How to turn a jp2 image to a jpg file?

Tags: php, jpeg, gd

How to turn a jp2 image to a jpg image in php using the gd library.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. `GD2` doesn't support JP2 (JPG 2000) format.

You will have to use `Imagick` library.

I had 1.4million image files in jp2 format, and I used IrfanView batch function. It event let me re-cosntruct the directory structure, which consisted of three levels, like [0-f]/[0-f]/[0=f]/image.jpg